# Why make is locking up?

Tags: makefile

I've defined below function inside makefile.

```
# check debug xdc
define check_debug_xdc
    if [ -f ${DEBUG_XDC} ]; then \
        ...
    fi
endef
```

make runs fine, if directly call it.

```
# Optimize
${OUTPUTS1}: ${INPUTS1}
    @echo ""
    @echo "Optimization"
    @date '+%Y_%m%d_%H%M'
    @$(call check_debug_xdc)
```

But if I commented out DEBUG_XDC and put `$(call check_debug_xdc)` inside if-fi to check whether DEBUG_XDC is defined or not, make stops responding, nothing is printing out, even the date.

```
# DEBUG_XDC     = ./fpga_ila/fpga_ila.srcs/constrs_1/new/${TOP}.xdc  
...
# Optimize
${OUTPUTS1}: ${INPUTS1}
    @echo ""
    @echo "Optimization"
    @date '+%Y_%m%d_%H%M'
    @if [ ! -z "${DEBUG_XDC}" ]; then $(call check_debug_xdc); fi
```

Tried make -dn, it prints below message then stop responding.

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `makefile'.
    ...
         Finished prerequisites of target file `fpga/fpga_opt.dcp'.
        Must remake target `fpga/fpga_opt.dcp'.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Based only on what you've said here it looks like a bug in make.  That version of GNU make is almost 15 years old; I recommend you try with a newer version and if you still see the same problem let us know.

Comment: The trigger is likely not in the parts you quoted. Have you tried removing the `@`? Does the actual shell command look reasonable?

Comment: Based on the debug output posted at the end of the question it doesn't look like the shell command is even being invoked (there's no output about "starting job" etc.)  If so removing `@` won't help.  So I was suspecting there was an infinite loop trying to expand the recipe.  But it's impossible to know without more information.

Comment: Do you expect `${DEBUG_XDC}` to be a Make variable (which is what it is currently being interpreted as) or a shell variable (in which case use `$${DEBUG_XDC}`)?

Comment: @tripleee, DEBUG_XDC is a Make variable and it has been commented out.